# XSLT 2.0 to renumber hierarchical string in format (x.y.z)

Tags: xml, xslt

I have elements containing attributes which I need to renumber sequentially to tidy up a ton of gaps that have crept into the XML. My source looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li book="1" chapter="1" page="1"/>
    <li book="1" chapter="6" page="2"/>
    <li book="2" chapter="2" page="3"/>
    <li book="5" chapter="3" page="1"/>
</ul>
```

I want to create a list which looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li>1.1.1</li>
    <li>1.2.1</li>
    <li>2.1.1</li>
    <li>3.1.1</li>
</ul>
```

I'm essentially grouping by book, then chapter, then page, and restarting the count for each level (e.g. my second row 1.6.2 is the second chapter in book 1, but the first page in the second chapter so it becomes 1.2.1).

So far I've made the assumption that I need a for-each-group:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="descendant::li" group-by="concat(@book,'.',@chapter,'.',@page)">
    <xsl:sort select="@book" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    <xsl:sort select="@chapter" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    <xsl:sort select="@page" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    <xsl:variable name="a" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="concat(@book,'.',@chapter)">
        <xsl:variable name="c" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="@book">
            <xsl:variable name="b" select="position()"/>
            <!-- Renumbered -->
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($a,'.',$b,'.',$c)"/>
            </li>
            <!-- Original (for check) -->
            <!--<li>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(current-group()[1]/@book,'.',current-group()[1]/@chapter,'.',current-group()[1]/@page)"/>
            </li>-->
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Thing is, I think I'd need to do a group by at multiple levels (by @book to renumber the @chapter, and by @book,@chapter to renumber the @page) to return the correct position() in the for-each-group, which to my knowledge isn't possible. I appreciate my code is nowhere near at the moment, but I can't think where to take this next.

Keen to get an XSLT 2.0 solution. Thanks for your time - it's really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is simpler than you're making it.  You don't need the concat business, just group by one attribute at each level.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="li" group-by="@book">
  <xsl:variable name="book" select="position()" />
  <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="@chapter">
    <xsl:variable name="chapter" select="position()" />
    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="@page">
      <xsl:variable name="page" select="position()" />
      <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="$book, $chapter, $page" separator="." /></li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:-for-each-group>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

If you need to sort, then just put the one appropriate `<xsl:sort>` at each level.